# Nodes position within scene size

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode, skscene

In my SKScene, I am making a simple space shooter game. How can I make sure that my enemies always appear within the screen size regardless of which iphone the game is played at?

In other words words, how do I calculate the max and min X-coordinates of the scene size and more importantly how do i know what's the current scene size depending on which iphone the game is run at?

Comment: You need to explain the model of your game,  do you plan on having bigger scenes see more of the play area, or do you expect the images to get bigger on bigger devices

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the images should get bigger on bigger devices

Answer (score 1):

Don't resize your scene depend by iPhone model, leave Sprite-kit do this kind of job:

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
```

> The scene is not scaled to match the view. Instead, the scene is
>   automatically resized so that its dimensions always matches those of
>   the view.

About the size, when a scene is first initialized, its [size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/size) property is configured by the designated initializer. The size of the scene specifies the size of the visible portion of the scene in points. This is only used to specify the visible portion of the scene.

---

**Update** to help you in positioning:

If you want to set your positions instead to use scaleMode you can 
set your `scene.scaleMode` to **.AspectFill** for this to work on all scenes and the scene size has to be *2048x1536* or *1536x2048*. This will make it scaleable for iPad too.

```
class StartScene: SKScene {
    let playableArea: CGRect!
}

override init(size: CGSize) {

    //1. Get the aspect ratio of the device
    let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let deviceHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = deviceWidth / deviceHeight
    //2. For landscape orientation, use this
    let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)

    //3. For portrait orientation, use this
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: playableMargin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

    super.init(size: size)
}
```

So you can positioning your object with:

```
ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(playableArea), y: CGRectGetMaxY(playableArea) - (ball.size.height * 0.90))
```

**This code works in the iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, 6, 6 Plus, 6S, 6S Plus, and iPads**.

If you want to see your borders (for debug or not):

```
func drawWorkArea() {
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, workArea)
    shape.path = path
    shape.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    shape.lineWidth = 8
    addChild(shape)
}
```

Comment: the problem i am having is not about resizing of view when the iPhone version changes. It's about the positioning of my enemies when i spawn them. They go out of the edges sometimes or remain half-in and half-out. The problem I am having is calculating the range of x-coordination on which they are allowed to spawn

Comment: For example, if your developing on an iPhone 6S and the screen looks perfect, I would divide the frame size by the desired screen mode width. This will give you a float which would be equal to the screen ratio. So if a user is using a smaller device, the float would be 0.XX vs a larger device of X.XX. The iPhone 6S would be equal to 1.00. You would then multiply the image size, speed, distance, etc by the ratio.

Comment: I am losing you about the part where you explain the calculations. can you please tell me in terms of code? what i was doing was setting a min x-value and a max x-value. my min was = screen.size.width/6 and max = screen.size.width. then i was choosing a random value between these bounds

Comment: Check my update, hope it can help you to better understand what I mean.

Comment: @OsaamaShehzad if you are doing aspectfill,  then just set the size of your scene to something that is a 9:16 ratio,  this will allow the cut off to be on the top and the bottom instead of the sides for non 9:16 devices

Comment: Alessandro, as much as I appreciate sharing this with me, I am embarrassed because I do not understand it. I am very new to swift and I am unable to follow what each line is doing, specially the workArea in the function's arguments.

Comment: @OsaamaShehzad Try to understand line per line, what the code do in this moment an try to reply the same code to a blank project , use console debug and breakpoints to see in real-time what are the actual values of your properties. Step by step I think you can understand all the code. Good work.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano okay, i will do that. but what is workArea?